# software/firefox addon to grab website

Tags: windows

is there any software or firefox addon to grab an webpage. Like html, css, images, javascripts, flash, etc. So that I can use it as a template? It can be grabbed manually by viewing the source. but I want to do it easily.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [Wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) for this. It is a very powerful, scriptable commandline utility to grab a web page, a whole site, or any other combination. It supports a hosts of features to make sure you're getting the page you want (aka different Agent headers to pretend it's an IE, Firefox, Safari, Android or iPhone browser).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the information. I have downloaded wget-latest.tar.gz file and extracted them. But cannot find the way to use it. Can you help me using this? I am using 32 bit win xp.

Comment: You should get the win32 specific build here : http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm

Comment: As the question is tagged for Windows I doubt this will help.

Comment: I've used WGet for years on windows. The binaries are prebuilt for windows platform too.

Answer (score 0):

Go to menu `File->Save Page As`...